# Visual Basic to C#: load binary file in a string

Tags: c#, string, encoding, binary, vb6

I've to convert a project from old VB6 to c#, the aim is to preserve the old code as much possible as I can, for a matter of time.

A function of the old project loads a binary file into a string variable, and then this variable is analyzezed in its single characters values with the asc function:

OLD VB Code:

```
Public Function LoadText(ByVal DirIn As String) As String
    Dim FileBuffer As String
    Dim LenghtFile As Long
    Dim ContIN As Long

    ContIN = FreeFile
    Open DirIn For Binary Access Read As #ContIN
    LenghtFile = LOF(ContIN)
    FileBuffer = Space(LenghtFile)
    Get #ContIN, , FileBuffer
    Close #ContIN
    LoadText = FileBuffer
    'following line for test purpose
    debug.print(asc(mid(filebuffer,1,1)))
    debug.print(asc(mid(filebuffer,2,1)))
    debug.print(asc(mid(filebuffer,3,1)))
End Function

SUB Main
    dim testSTring as String
    teststring=loadtext("e:\testme.bin")
end sub
```

Result in immediate window:

1

10

133

C# code:

```
public static string LoadText(string dirIn)
    {

        string myString, myString2;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(dirIn, FileMode.Open);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

        byte[] bin = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
        //myString = Convert.ToBase64String(bin);

        myString =  Encoding.Default.GetString(bin);
        string m1 = Encoding.Default.GetString(bin);
        //string m1 =  Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bin);  
        //string m1 =  Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(bin);
        //string m1 = Encoding.UTF32.GetString(bin);
        //string m1 = Encoding.UTF7.GetString(bin);
        //string m1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bin);
        //string m1 = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bin);
        //string m1 = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bin);


        Console.WriteLine(General.Asc(m1.Substring(0, 1)));
        Console.WriteLine(General.Asc(m1.Substring(1, 1)));
        Console.WriteLine(General.Asc(m1.Substring(2, 1)));

        br.Close();
        fs.Close();
        return myString;
}
```

General class:

```
public static int Asc(string stringToEValuate)
{
    return (int)stringToEValuate[0];
}
```

Result in output window:

1

10

8230  <--fail!

The string in VB6 has a length 174848, identical to the size of the test file.

In c# is the same size for DEFAUILT and ASCII encoding, while all the others has different size and i cannot use them unless i change everithing in the whole project.

The problem is that I can't find the correct encoding that permits to have a string which asc function returns identical numbers to the VB6 one.

The problem is all there, if the string is not identical I have to change a lot of lines of code, because the whole program is based on ASCii value and the position of it in the string.

Maybe it's the wrong way to load a binary into a string, or the Asc function..

If you want to try the example file you can download it from here:

http:// www.snokie.org / testme.bin

Comment: Having gone through a task like this in the past, you don't want to retain old code. It will cause you more headaches than its worth.  Even if you were to go VB6 to VB.Net I would recommend rewriting it all

Comment: Have you tried to look at what are the values stored in your byte array?

Comment: Have you thried to instantiate the BinaryReader with encoding:BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII);

Answer (score 0):

8230 *is* correct. It is a UTF-16 code unit for the Unicode codepoint (U+2026, which only needs one UTF-16 code unit). You expected 133. 133 as one byte is the encoding for the same character in at least one other character set: Windows-1252.

There is no text but encoded text.

When you read a text file you have to know the encoding that was used to write it. Once you read into a .NET String or Char, you have it in Unicode's UTF-16 encoding. Because Unicode is a superset of any character set you would be using, it is not incorrect.

If you don't want to compare characters as characters, read them as binary to keep it in them in the same encoding as the file. You can then compare the byte sequences.

The problem is that the VB6 code, rather than using Unicode for character code like it should have, used the "default ANSI" character set, which changes meaning from system to system and user to user.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this: "old project loads a binary file into a string variable". Yes, this was a common—but bad—VB6 practice. String datatypes are for text. Strings in VB6 are UTF-16 code unit sequences, just like in .NET (and Java, JavaScript, HTML, XML, …).

`Get #ContIN, , FileBuffer` converts from the system's default ANSI code page to UTF-16 and `Asc` converts it back again. So, you just have to do that in your .NET code, too.

Note: Just like in the VB6, Encoding.Default is hazardous because it can vary from system to system and user to user.

Reference Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll and

```
using static Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings;
```

Then

```
var fileBuffer = File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.Default); 
Debug.WriteLine(Asc(Mid(fileBuffer, 3, 1));
```

If you'd rather not bring Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll into a C# project, you can write your own versions

```
static class VB6StringReplacements
{
    static public Byte Asc(String source) => 
        Encoding.Default.GetBytes(source.Substring(0,1)).FirstOrDefault();

    static public String Mid(String source, Int32 offset, Int32 length) => 
        source.Substring(offset, length);
}
```

and, change your using directive to

```
using static VB6StringReplacements;
```